# JBI-Free Normalized Message Router

Tags: esb, apache-servicemix, jbi

The normalized message router (`NMR`) is the part of the `JBI` environment that is responsible for mediating messages between `JBI` components; ServiceMix 4 has moved from `JBI` to `OSGI`. However, I  read somewhere we still can use `NMR` without `JBI` based ServiceMix (`JBI-free NMR`). What does this mean? Any example that I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ActiveMQ and JMS as the "JBI-free NMR". In fact it was ActiveMQ JMS queues that the JBI NMR uses under the covers.

In ServiceMix 4.x you can use Camel and JMS queues as your NMR if you want. And the messages do not need to be normalized anymore, eg they can be of any type, as opposed to JBI where the message must be XML.

Comment: I am not sure what you ask. See the Camel JMS component: http://camel.apache.org/jms

Comment: I have the link for Camel NMR. How about link for using JMS as NMR?

Comment: For JMS as NMR, then use Camel flows with JMS.